# Cannot resolve method 'getBaseContext()' in class extends BaseAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I am trying to use firebase remote config feature in my App. But I am getting error 
"Cannot resolve method 'getBaseContext()'". My class extends BaseAdapter which looks like below. I am restricted to use method only please help.

```
    public class CustomAdapter_new extends BaseAdapter {
.....
......
........
         private void initRemoteConfig() {
        mRemoteConfig = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance();

        Resources res = context.getResources();

        HashMap<String, Object> defaults = new HashMap<>();
        defaults.put("claimStatusEnquiry", context.getResources().getString(R.string.claimStatusEnquiry));        defaults.put("locateYourPfOffice", context.getResources().getString(R.string.locateYourOffice));
        defaults.put("faq", context.getResources().getString(R.string.faq));

        mRemoteConfig.setDefaults(defaults);
        FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings remoteConfigSettings = new FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings.Builder()
                .setDeveloperModeEnabled(true)
                .build();
        mRemoteConfig.setConfigSettings(remoteConfigSettings);
        fetchRemoteConfigValues();
    }

    private void fetchRemoteConfigValues() {
        long cacheExpiration = 600;

        //expire the cache immediately for development mode.
        if (mRemoteConfig.getInfo().getConfigSettings().isDeveloperModeEnabled()) {
            cacheExpiration = 0;
        }

        mRemoteConfig.fetch(cacheExpiration)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(Task<Void> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // task successful. Activate the fetched data
                            mRemoteConfig.activateFetched();

                        } else {
                            //task failed
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please Connect To Internet!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
    }
```

Comment: The compiler doesn't lie. Your class has not method named `getBaseContext()`. You either must provide this yourself or find the correct class to extend as [`BaseAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html) does not provide this method for you.

Comment: How do you call `fetchRemoteConfigValues()`?

Comment: `Resources res = context.getResources();` What is `context` in this line? Where did you declare and initialize it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler doesn't lie. Your class has no method named `getBaseContext()`. [`BaseAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html) does not provide this method for you. However, you need a `Context` object in order to create a `Toast`. There are many ways to gain access to a `Context`. It appears that you already have one available since you use it in the line

```
Resources res = context.getResources();
```

Most likely, you should just replace `getBaseContext()` with `context`:

```
Toast.makeText(context, ...).show();
```

I strongly suggest you learn more about variable scope, class fields, and method parameters. These are all fundamental concepts in Java. If you understand how these all work, you will have a much easier time writing Android app.s

Comment: I have edited my code please check it in question. When i use"private void fetchRemoteConfigValues(Context context) " I get another error where i call "fetchRemoteConfigValues()" as :Error:(213, 9) error: method fetchRemoteConfigValues in class CustomAdapter_new cannot be applied to given types;
required: Context
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: @ArbazAlam The error is telling you that you need to send a parameter to the `fetchRemoteConfigValues()` method.

Comment: @ArbazAlam Based on the code in your recent edit, I have modified my proposed solution. This is an educated guess since you still are missing some details in the code you posted.